# Rolling Quarter Calculation by Month While Using Another Column to group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to calculate rolling percentages for quarterly time periods. Sample data via sql is below:

```
create table #demo (Month char(7), Type varchar(10), Mileage int);
--low
insert into #demo values ('2021-05', 'low', 5000);
insert into #demo values ('2021-06', 'low', 15000);
insert into #demo values ('2021-07', 'low', 3000);
insert into #demo values ('2021-08', 'low', 3500);

-- med
insert into #demo values ('2021-05', 'med', 6789);
insert into #demo values ('2021-06', 'med', 12876);
insert into #demo values ('2021-07', 'med', 1578);
insert into #demo values ('2021-08', 'med', 3500);


--high
insert into #demo values ('2021-05', 'high', 5000);
insert into #demo values ('2021-06', 'high', 1500);
insert into #demo values ('2021-07', 'high', 2700);
insert into #demo values ('2021-08', 'high', 2968);
```

```
Month   Type    Mileage
2021-05 high    5000
2021-05 low     5000
2021-05 med     6789
2021-06 high    1500
2021-06 low     15000
2021-06 med     12876
2021-07 high    2700
2021-07 low     3000
2021-07 med     1578
2021-08 high    2968
2021-08 low     3500
2021-08 med     3500
```

My goal is to take this data and calculate the rolling 3 month percentage for each category individually.

Example:
for the first 3 months of 2021 I would desire to get the sum(low mileage), sum(med mileage), sum (high mileage) for 2021-05, 2021-06, 2021-07 and then divide each sum by the total of those three months (for all categories). I'm imagining a PIVOT solution would be ideal here. I'm just not sure how to go about it.

So I would expect to see rolling totals like:

```
Month    ThreeMonth_TotalMileage ThreeMonth_Low  ThreeMonth_Med ThreeMonth_High
2021-05  NULL                    NULL            NULL           NULL
2021-06  NULL                    NULL            NULL           NULL
2021-07  53443                   23000           21243          9200
2021-08  46622                   18800           17954          7168
```

E.g. ThreeMonth_TotalMileage is the sum of all mileage for 2021-05, 2021-06, 2021-07. This will only show as a running total in 2021-07 since we have 3 months of history we can calculate a sum from, otherwise I'd like it to be null.

3Month_Low is the sum of all low mileage for 2021-05, 2021-06, 2021-07, basically its inclusive of the current month plus the prior 2 for each calc.

Any ideas on how I could try to accomplish this using SQL Server? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that using [Ordered Analytical Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/analytic-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). The idea is to find cumulative sum.

For Pivoting the data from row to column, you can use `CASE` and `MAX`.

```
select
Month
,Max(case when Type='low' then Mileage end)  as Month_Low
,Max(case when Type='med' then Mileage end)as Month_Med
,Max(case when Type='high' then Mileage end)  as Month_High
,case when ROW_NUMBER() over(order by Month asc)>=3 Then 1 end as is_3month_data_present
from #demo
group by month
```

| Month | Month_Low | Month_Med | Month_High | is_3month_data_present |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05 | 5000 | 6789 | 5000 | null |
| 2021-06 | 15000 | 12876 | 1500 | null |
| 2021-07 | 3000 | 1578 | 2700 | 1 |
| 2021-08 | 3500 | 3500 | 2968 | 1 |

Below SQL should give the desired final result.

```
select
Month
,case when is_3month_data_present=1 then Sum(Month_Low+Month_Med+Month_High) over(order by Month ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW )  end as ThreeMonth_TotalMileage   
,case when is_3month_data_present=1 then Sum(Month_Low) over(order by Month ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW )  end as ThreeMonth_Low  
,case when is_3month_data_present=1 then Sum(Month_Med ) over(order by Month ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW ) end as ThreeMonth_Med 
,case when is_3month_data_present=1 then Sum(Month_High) over(order by Month ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING and CURRENT ROW ) end  as ThreeMonth_High
from
(select
Month
,Max(case when Type='low' then Mileage end)  as Month_Low
,Max(case when Type='med' then Mileage end)as Month_Med
,Max(case when Type='high' then Mileage end)  as Month_High
,case when ROW_NUMBER() over(order by Month asc)>=3 Then 1 end as is_3month_data_present
from #demo
group by Month
)stg
```

**Output:**

| Month | ThreeMonth_TotalMileage | ThreeMonth_Low | ThreeMonth_Med | ThreeMonth_High |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05 | null | null | null |  |
| 2021-06 | null | null | null |  |
| 2021-07 | 53443 | 23000 | 21243 | 9200 |
| 2021-08 | 46622 | 21500 | 17954 | 7168 |

**Note:** Expected output provided in the question is wrong as per the dataset given. ThreeMonth_low is wrong, rest all are correct. For 2021-07, actual value should be `23000` instead of `20300`.

DB Fiddle: [Try it here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=de69d90853b0c725185eff5fcc621ec1)

Comment: Excellent. Good catch on the typo, made a mistake when uploading the question. Really appreciate your response.